# markdownify don't remove comment from tag

Tags: python, markdown

I try to convert HTML to Markdown using `markdownify`. This lib don't remove comment from style tag and I try to understand it.

One of methods of MarkdownConverter class is `process_tag`, and I think that key somewhere here. See below (I add some prints to check):

```
def process_tag(self, node, convert_as_inline, children_only=False):
    text = ''

    # markdown headings or cells can't include
    # block elements (elements w/newlines)
    isHeading = html_heading_re.match(node.name) is not None
    isCell = node.name in ['td', 'th']
    convert_children_as_inline = convert_as_inline

    if not children_only and (isHeading or isCell):
        convert_children_as_inline = True
    
    print(f"convert_children_as_inline = {convert_children_as_inline}")

    # Remove whitespace-only textnodes in purely nested nodes
    def is_nested_node(el):
        return el and el.name in ['ol', 'ul', 'li',
                                  'table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot',
                                  'tr', 'td', 'th']

    if is_nested_node(node):
        for el in node.children:
            # Only extract (remove) whitespace-only text node if any of the
            # conditions is true:
            # - el is the first element in its parent
            # - el is the last element in its parent
            # - el is adjacent to an nested node
            can_extract = (not el.previous_sibling
                           or not el.next_sibling
                           or is_nested_node(el.previous_sibling)
                           or is_nested_node(el.next_sibling))
            if (isinstance(el, NavigableString)
                    and six.text_type(el).strip() == ''
                    and can_extract):
                el.extract()

    # Convert the children first
    for i, el in enumerate(node.children):
        cl = None
        if isinstance(el, Comment):
            cl = "Comment"
        elif isinstance(el, Doctype):
            cl = "Doctype"
        elif isinstance(el, NavigableString):
            cl = "NavigableString"
        else:
            cl = "Other" 
        print(f"{i}, cl = {cl}, el = {el}")
        if isinstance(el, Comment) or isinstance(el, Doctype):
            continue
        elif isinstance(el, NavigableString):
            text += self.process_text(el)
        else:
            text += self.process_tag(el, convert_children_as_inline)

    if not children_only:
        convert_fn = getattr(self, 'convert_%s' % node.name, None)
        if convert_fn and self.should_convert_tag(node.name):
            text = convert_fn(node, text, convert_as_inline)

    return text
```

My test file consists of two parts:

```
<style><!-- 1. some style defenitions --></style>

<!-- 2. some style definitions -->
```

What I see in terminal:

```
convert_children_as_inline = False
0, cl = NavigableString, el =  
1, cl = Other, el = <style><!-- 1. some style defenitions --></style>
convert_children_as_inline = False
0, cl = NavigableString, el = <!-- 1. some style defenitions -->
2, cl = NavigableString, el = 

3, cl = Comment, el =  2. some style definitions
```

And what I see in out file:

`<!-- 1. some style defenitions -->`

Please explain me why converter didn't determine string `<!-- 1. some style defenitions -->` like a comment. I'm a bit confuse about it because the second part it determine like comment (I want to get an empty out file).

Comment: would using the `strip` parameter solve this for you?

Comment: @JonSG unfortunately no. `strip` controls directly tags and its attributes not text. E.g. `markdownify("<b>bold</b>") -> **bold**`, but `markdownify("<b>bold</b>", strip=["b"]) -> bold` and `markdownify("<img src='url' alt='some image'>") -> ![some image](url)`, but `markdownify("<img src='url' alt='some image'>", strip=["img"]) -> ""`

Comment: Just a note: HTML comments are not valid content of `<style>` elements, which must contain valid CSS. So this seems like very reasonable behavior.

Comment: @tarleb I receive this by email message that was sent via MS Outlook and lib doesn't know anything about what data can be valid in a particular tag. It just looks through the tags one by one and convert their contents one way or another. 

Besides this lib can convert inline tags. E.g. `mardownify("<h2><b>Bold</b> Title</h2>") - > "**Bold** Title\n--------------"`. 

It seems reasonable to expect that nested comments will also be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the reasons for what is happening, but I tryed to deal with the consequences.

I created derived class and add to it method `convert_style` that return an empty string:

```py
def convert_style(self, el, text, convert_as_inline):
    return ""
```

If you have any suggestions about the question or the solution, I'd glad to see it.

Comment: If it works it ain't stupid!